# How to ask for help writing a package?

Tags: discussion, support, packages

I'm currently working on a package that extends the functionality of dblfnote. I've finished a method for placing the footnote rule at an arbitrary horizontal location (more specifically, centered on the page), and I'm in the process of debugging a way to have two column paragraph footnotes (which is coming along in a promising way. You can see what I have in [my github repo](https://github.com/rabbiveesh/dfn-para)).

The question is: how can I ask for help in testing and implementing these features? Is this the right place?

Also, how should I let people know about my work. I feel like I'm not the only person who wants paragraph footnotes in two columns. Can I ask a question about it on the main site, and post my package as an answer?

Comment: If you have a problem to solve then TeX.Stackexchange is the right place. If you want feedback/testing on something you have already implemented, I would tend to codereview.stackexchange.com (worked great when I sought feedback for my tikzducks package), although we already had such questions on TeX.Stackexchange.

Comment: You can also ask in chat if anybody would be willing to test it. This is a bit hit or miss as chat is so ephemeral, but it is worth a shot.

Comment: find questions and answer them with your package. That's how most people jump on the bandwagon

Comment: To let people know about your work, you could also consider submitting the package to ctan - if people have easy access to your package without manually installing it, they may be more likely to use it.

Comment: @Samcarter is it customary to put beta versions on ctan?

Comment: @AGoldMan I don't think there is a general rule. My personal opinion: if the package is usable by the ordinary user, put it on ctan. (you have to judge what state your package is in)